# If I'm using the pen tool in Photoshop to create a long, curved, line, is it possible to find the length of the line?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool

I have a map on Photoshop that I'm drawing a path on using the brush tool (with the spacing on the brush settings at 164% to make the lines dotted, if that matters at all.) I'd like to find out what the distance of the path's total length is. My plan would be to use the pen tool to trace over the path that I've made to get a close estimate, but this only works if I can find the length of a line that was made using the pen tool. **Is it possible to find the length of a line that I've made with the pen tool?**

My guess would be no, since what I've seen so far from similar questions makes it seem like the the equations that Photoshop uses to store the lines don't have a way to store the line's length. If there's something I'm missing and there's a possible way to find the path's length, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can measure it by **Measurement Log**!
You just select your path and go to **Window** to load up the **Measurement Log**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Area is not the same as length, perimeter is IF the line he was measuring is closed.

Comment: ...and probably should mention that you need to load a path as a selection first